# SQL to loop / run based on Sequence column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write up a query that will loop/ run for each sequential pair in the row_num column in the join for the query below. The sequence is based on the weekstart date, with most recent being 1.

So 1+2 , 2+3, 3+4 , 4+5, 5+6 and so on.

The data itself is account based and is updated weekly, and account can drop out/be added each week. So in essence each week update will only include accounts active in that week. This data appends each week to one master table (BaseTable). We use this to generate another table (NewTable) that calculates the status based on the sequence column.

I need the joins in the below table to change and run through each of the sequences for row_num

```
     SELECT CASE WHEN B1.ACCOUNTNo IS NULL THEN 'EXPIRED'
    WHEN B2.ACCOUNTNo IS NULL AND B1.ACCOUNTNo IS NOT NULL THEN 'New'
    ELSE 'Carried Forward' END AS Status 
    FROM 
   (SELECT *
   FROM BaseTable
   WHERE Row_num = 1
   )AS B1
   FULL OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT *
   FROM BaseTable
   WHERE Row_num = 2
   ) AS B2 
   ON B1.ACCOUNTNo = B2.ACCOUNTNo
```

I want to run a query so I get counts of how the total number of accounts in each stage changes week on week.

BaseTable

| Weekstart | ACCOUNTNo | Row_num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/5/22 | A1 | 1 |
| 30/5/22 | B1 | 1 |
| 23/5/22 | A1 | 2 |
| 23/5/22 | C1 | 2 |
| 16/5/22 | A1 | 3 |
| 23/5/22 | C1 | 3 |

NewTable

| Weekstart | ACCOUNT NO | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/5/22 | A1 | Continue |
| 30/5/22 | B1 | New |
| 23/5/22 | A1 | Continue |
| 23/5/22 | C1 | Expired |
| 16/5/22 | A1 | New |
| 16/5/22 | C1 | Continue |

Expected Results:

| Weekstart | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30/5/22 | Continue | 1 |
| 30/5/22 | New | 1 |
| 23/5/22 | Continue | 1 |
| 23/5/22 | Expired | 1 |
| 16/5/22 | New | 1 |
| 16/5/22 | Continue | 1 |

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please retag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. Though wanting to use a loop in SQL is normally a miskake; SQL is a set based language and so you should be wanting to implement set based solutions, not iterative ones.

Comment: thanks have added the correct tag, and wasn't sure how to word the questions so went with loop. But open to any suggestions